# buffer memory in the delay operator in Modelica

Tags: delay, modelica, openmodelica

In OpenModelcia, do all variables of a model save in the ring buffer only when the delay operator is used, or is it done automatically whether we use delay or not? and if so, can we access the ring buffer from an external function C?

Answer (score 1):

Since Modelica models can fail at any point in time all variables are saved in some sort of backup, for the C runtime in some buffers in the so-called [`thread data`](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/OMCompiler/SimulationRuntime/c/gc/omc_gc.h#L118-L145). And in some cases the OpenModelica compiler is able to revert the last step and try again, but slightly different.
For example an assert is throwing an error, because some variable has become negative but wasn't allowed to, so the compiler tries again with a smaller step size.
This backup is done independent of the presence of the `delay` operator and always done.

For the delay operator a [different data structure](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/OMCompiler/SimulationRuntime/c/simulation_data.h#L745) is used, which is the `RINGBUFFER` you are probably referring to. It is only allocated if there are `delay` operators in the Modelica model.

There are no API functions provided to access (this) internal data of a OpenModelica simulation. So accessing the ring buffer would only be possible if you write such a function yourself, which is of course possible.
Question would be what you are trying to accomplish in the first place.